# Why AJAX doesn't work on my local

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, servlets

I have been following an [AJAX Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4VgHJCAKZZQ) and I did the same thing as he does but i don't why it doesn't work for me. Here's what i have done.

**index.jsp**
At the header i placed some source script

```
<script src="../javascript/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="../javascript/basic.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/basic.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

and at the body a simple snippnet is made

```
<p class="large">Test AJAX</p>
    <form id="updateUsername">
        <label for="username">What is your name?</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
<p id="displayName" />
```

**basic.js**
Code for the ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#updateUsername').submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'update',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'jason',
            data: $('#updateUsername'),
            success: function(data){
                if(data.isValid){
                    $('#displayName').html('Your name is: ' + data.username);
                    $('#displayName').slideDown(500);
                }
                else {
                    alert('Please enter a valid username !!');
                }
            } 
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

**UpdateUsername.java**
the servlet

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        boolean isValid = false;
        String username = request.getParameter( "username" );
        if( username != null && username.trim().length() != 0 )
        {
            isValid = true;
            map.put( "username", username );
        }
        map.put( "isValid", isValid );
        write( response, map ); // WRITE METHOD
```

and lastly the write method from the servlet

```
response.setContentType( "application/json" );
        response.setCharacterEncoding( "UTF-8" );
        response.getWriter().write( new Gson().toJson( map ) );
```

Do i need some setup before it works for me? When i test it out the url is like this `http://localhost:8080/TestProject/?username=test`, seems like the `POST` doesn't work. Did i miss something?

**UPDATE** 
I changed from 
`$('#displayName'),slideDown(500);` to `$('#displayName').slideDown(500);`

By the way i did change the `charset` and some other to `UTF-8`. At the top most of the `index.jsp`

`<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`

and at the head `<meta charset="utf-8">`

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>UpdateUsername</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.ajax.servlets.UpdateUsername</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>UpdateUsername</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/update</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Image of the result
[image: Image result]

Comment: Did you map your servlet to `/TestProject/`?  You won't be able to test a servlet with a `doPOST()` via the command line (they are different HTTP request types)

Comment: Has your servlet the name update in web.xml , also is your class located in a package ?

Comment: I'm using annotation `@WebServlet( "/update" )` at my servlet

Comment: ok can you show me what happens when you click submit button,show me output of console in your browser,to know if there is some 404 errors or 500 internal error in server

Comment: I updated the question see the web xml and the image, I removed my annotation and set it up at the web xml

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `http://localhost:8080/TestProject/?username=test` does not look like a `POST` request. `POST` requests do not send request parameters as part of the `URL`. If you want to send the `POST`, and send some parameters along with that then you need to send the params as part of the body.

From Jasoon Sperske comment:

Also `data: $('#updateUsername')` needs a value and name like: data: `{username: $('#updateUsername').val()}`

Comment: Also the `data: $('#updateUsername')` needs a value and name like: `data: {username: $('#updateUsername').val()}`

Comment: Actually on closer inspection I think you need to call `$('#updateUsername').serialize()` as the selector is the form itself.

Comment: I tried data: `username: $('#updateUsername').val()` but still the post doesn't work

Comment: I also tried $('#updateUsername').serialize() but doesn't work either

Comment: @newbie Are you sure that you are passing the param in request body and not as part of URL?

Comment: @JunedAhsan i placed the code at the post method and `name` and `id` tag is really `username` so i guess it's a yes

Answer (score 0):

I guess dataType: 'jason' Should be dataType: 'json'

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the "," in the following line?

```
$('#displayName'),slideDown(500);
```

Comment: Also check out the other answers. They've pointed out a couple other issues with the code.